# DataColumn DataType int and long

Tags: c#, datatable

Is it possible to have a DataColumn in a DataTable that contains int and long values?  It should return an int value if a valid int else it should return a long value.

For some background why I want to achieve this, I have released a product that creates the DataColumn of type int, but it should have been long from the start. Now I don't want to break existing projects that explicitly casts the value to int, but I would like to allow long values in the column.

Is there an event I can subscribe to on the DataTable to convert the value to int?

The following code should execute correctly.

```
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("IntAndLong", typeof(long));

        DataRow intRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        intRow[0] = 123;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(intRow);

        DataRow longRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        longRow[0] = 3000000000;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(longRow);

        long longValue = (long)dataTable.Rows[1][0];
        int intValue = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest collecting the datacolumn value in a long type variable, check its value to be less than int.MaxValue and bigger than int.MinValue and then cast it to an int variable if you need it there.

Comment: Where should the check be done?  This could be existing code that I do not have access to, so this line of code must keep on working.  

int intValue = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];

Comment: int intVal = (longVal < long.MaxValue) ? (int)longVal : int.MaxValue; I am tempted to propose this piece of code but then you say there might be code you do not have access to. In that case how about trapping it through the view or stored procedure that exposes the result.

Comment: Thanks for you help Raj.  I don't think there is a solution to this problem.  The code has to be changed to explicitly cast it to a long.